# SET FLASK_APP not working in Anaconda, can only run if using app.py

Tags: python, flask

I am activating a conda environment, setting FLASK_APP = flaskblog.py - can see the environment variable set when I run the "SET" command, but am getting this error on Windows 10.

```
(ariel) C:\flask_blog>SET FLASK_APP = flaskblog.py

(ariel) C:\flask_blog>flask run
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.

(ariel) C:\flask_blog>dir
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 36E9-84F4

 Directory of C:\flask_blog

08/01/2020  12:57    <DIR>          .
08/01/2020  12:57    <DIR>          ..
08/01/2020  12:45    <DIR>          .vscode
08/01/2020  12:50               105 flaskblog.py
08/01/2020  12:55    <DIR>          __pycache__
               1 File(s)            105 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  298,386,743,296 bytes free
```

The only way I can get the application to run is to rename the flaskblog.py to app.py.

I am running from Anaconda prompt, not from PowerShell.

Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ahhhh....dont use a space when setting the environment variable.

```
SET FLASK_APP = flaskblog.py
```

should be

```
SET FLASK_APP=flaskblog.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your its because you didn't set the ENV for flask_app

if ur using powershell use this

```
$env:FLASK_APP = "hello"
flask run
```

if ur using cmd use this

```
set FLASK_APP=hello
flask run
```

for more detials look at the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/quickstart/)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtjQM.png)